# Phonegap Build - Get application root directory?

Tags: javascript, filesystems, cordova, phonegap-build

I am looking at porting an existing application to phonegap build, however as my application is a multi-page application with pages split in different locations and a resource loading mechanism which loads files from different places.

So I basically want to be able to get my applications root directory up front and then use that when initilizing the application. Then it does the rest itself once it knows the root directory and  has a file managing class which will build the file paths based off this root value.

I did notice this question:
[Getting application directory in phone gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763233/getting-application-directory-in-phone-gap)

However it does not seem to act the same on each platform, and I need this to be consistent. So is there a simple and consistent way to get a string representation of the applications root directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case after asking the guys at phonegap, they say that you dont really need to do any of this can just use `location.hostname` so am looking at using that approach for now, the main reason for asking this is because in trigger.io I would be using `tools.getUrl`. So I assumed in Phonegap I would need to do something similar.

http://legacy-docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/tools.html