# Write a file in phoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

I want to create file using the [PhoneGap API File Writer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter), but using data my file will create in root folder either memory card or phone memory, but actually I want to create that file. Where does my installed app go? How do I know that where my files are installed and how do I create a file at that location?

Here is what I have:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763233/getting-application-directory-in-phone-gap) last comment. So you can try to get /data/yourApp folder via fileSystem.root.getDirectory() etc. if it exists - so you are on sd card. go to the  /data/yourApp and write there. If it doesn't exists - the root is already you app folder - just write the file.