# Get internal application directory in Cordova + android

Tags: android, cordova

I would like to know how to get the path where the app is installed on Android using Cordova. I want to use file API to get this information.

I have tried the solution implemented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763233/getting-application-directory-in-phone-gap), namely:

```
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    console.log("got filesystem");
    // save the file system for later access
    console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath);
    window.rootFS = fileSystem.root;
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {                
    window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}, false);
```

However, this gives me some path to external storage: file:///storage/emulated/0/.

I think `requestFileSystem` gives you external storage path if there is one available. How can I force `requestFileSystem` to give me internal path? (`/data/data/appname`)

Comment: which plugin version are you using? the latest should use ```/data/data/appname```

Comment: @jcesarmobile You're right. From 3.0.0, the default persistent file location is internal. Can you post it as an answer? I will accept it. For people experiencing this issue: check out release note https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md#300-aug-18-2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from cordova file 3.0.0, the default `LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT` is the `/data/data/app.package`

on previous versions you can get it using

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory, success, fail);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find the application folder at:

```
/data/data/"your package name"
```

you can access this folder using the DDMS for your Emulator. you can't access this location on a real device unless you have a rooted device.

Comment: I want to use file API to retrieve that information. I am aware of this as you can see in the question. I will update the question to be more precise.